# Dynamic validation rules based on input in Larave

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

I'm wondering is there some rule in Laravel request validation that acts like required_if/required_unless but to checks if the value exists in a table.

For instance, I have a form with two fields - last_name and phone_number. After submitting the form I need to save these data into a table. However, I need to check if the phone number presents on the table. If the phone number already in the table I need to show an error but it should be possible to save data. Something like `unique_unless:ignore_duplicates:table,phone_number`

I see the flow something like this

1. fill the form and submit
2. request validated and message that phone number is already take shown
3. set a checkbox that I want ignore such errors and submit data again
4. request validated again but this time rule for uniqueness is skipped
5. save the data if no other errors occur

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything out-of-the-box that you could use here. But if I get your problem correctly, this can be solved with a [closure-based rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) like:

```php
$rules = [
    ...,
    'phone_number' => [
        ...,
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            if (! $request->input('override')) {
                if (YourModel::where('phone_number', $value)->first()) {
                    $fail("YourModel with this phone number already exists.");
                }
            }
        }
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the only solution.